# how to get esp32 ip address ,which is being connected to local network

Tags: arduino, iot, esp32

I need to know the IP address of ESP32 on the local network(without printing ip on serial monitor ). The idea is to do mDNS or UDP broadcast to send the IP to the **android application**. The app will then use that IP to do the communication. Is there someone who has already done it?

Comment: What about to assignate the ESP to a static IP adress?

Comment: its not what i wanted , static ip isnt not a good choice when you have several devices

Comment: Do not understand why, that is usually what you do when dealing with embedded devices on a local network, while letting other devices on dynamic. But maybe I did not get something…

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but nevertheless:

The function called "tcpip_adapter_get_ip_info" can be used to obtain your interface IP address, netmask and gateway. You can pass in TCPIP_ADAPTERE_IF_STA to get the information you desire.

```c
    #include <tcpip_adapter.h>

    tcpip_adapter_ip_info_t ipInfo; 
    char str[256];
        
    tcpip_adapter_get_ip_info(TCPIP_ADAPTER_IF_STA, &ipInfo);
    sprintf(str, "%x", ipInfo.ip.addr);
```

Note that it is also given in the event handler:

```c
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP:
        eprintf(eLOG_EVENTQ,"IP: %s\r\n", 
        ip4addr_ntoa(&event>event_info.got_ip.ip_info.ip));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to identify your ESP32 easily on the local network, you can simply use the [mDNS service](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/mdns.html).

This will make your ESP32 accessible via user friendly hostname.

Example: **myesp32.local**